# Automatically set the color of treemap labels based on background

Tags: echarts

I have made a treemap chart using Apache ECharts. I am using a color palette that goes from a light color to a dark color for the nodes. So for labels to be legible on the nodes I have to use both white and black. Is there a way to configure ECharts to automatically select an appropriate text color based on the background?

One option would be for me to manually assign colors for each nodes like,

```
const series = {
  type: 'treemap',
  data: [
      {
        name: 'nodeA',
        value: 10,
        label: { color: '#333' },
        itemStyle: { color: 'black' },
        children: [ ... ],
      },
  ]
}
```

But I would like to avoid this because the automatic color selection automatically sorts the nodes and assigns colors in order. I would have to replicate this.